# Iterate over 2D Array outward to boundaries from arbitrary coordinates

Tags: algorithm, swift, multidimensional-array, 2d, traversal

I'm currently trying to create a function in Swift to traverse a 2-dimensional array of any number of rows or columns.

For example:

```
let array: [[Int]] = [
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
]
```

The result of the algorithm would print out adjacent cells from an arbitrary row and column point, expanding outward in a square until all values in said square are outside the boundries of the array.

For example, if I selected array[row/2][col/2], ie: "2", the outputs would be:

```
[2], [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3], [2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3]
```

Currently I can get the immediate adjacent cells in the array by using a combination of an array of tuples with a for in loop, like so:

```
let adjacentCells: [(Int, Int)] = [
    (-1,-1), (0,-1), (1,-1), (-1,0), (1,0), (-1,1), (0,1), (1,1)
]

for (rowOffset, colOffset) in adjacentCells {
    if row+rowOffset >= 0 && row+rowOffset < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_ROWS && col+colOffset >= 0 && col+colOffset < TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS {
        // Store adjacent cell in new array for later use
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into Breadth first search. The algorithm with search outward in concentric rings as you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pixelscan/0.1.0) is a solution I wrote in python that can scan a grid of points in a ring pattern (either square or diamond). It also has a variety spatial patterns to scan.